# Flutter Error: Instance member 'user' can't be accessed using static access

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider, flutter-streambuilder

I/m facing this issue. Can anyone assist?
Thanks
[First page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HqQj9.jpg)

[Second page. Both pages are shown below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YXK4T.jpg)

Comment: Hi! Please embed your images directly into your question with the help of the markdown editor :)

Comment: Try `AuthService().user` -- notice the parenthesis.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to access a member via static access it needs to be marked as static like so:

```
static final myStaticFinalVariable;
```

Alternatively, you must instantiate the class first by creating an instance () to call an instance method.

```
AuthService().user
```

Comment: AuthService().user That was the problem! Thanks a lot!!